# Load image from url, using cycle

Tags: java, android, stream, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm using this code for downloading image from server:

```
public Bitmap getBitmap(String path){
    URL url=new URL(path);
    URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream is=connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
    return bmp;
}
```

It works fine for 1 image, but if I'm using this in cycle, on second, third etc iterations it returns something strange (Bitmap's `mWidth` and `mHeight` fields are `-1`). **Where can be the problem?**

(`path` on second, third etc. iterations are fine, I checked this)

**EDIT**

Example of cycle:

```
//images - is a String array
for(int i=0; i<images.length(); i++){
    Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(images[i]);
}
```

Ss you can see, there is nothing unusual in this cycle

Comment: Please, put here how you are making the cycle.

Comment: It seems to me that many people here downvotes really difficult questions that they don't know how to answer. I don't agree with such politics, so I put my upvote here.

Comment: @Gangnus, questions like "Where is error?" always sounds bad ) My mistake.

Comment: Heaps of askers here are asking to find the error. Senseless arre never punished. Repeated questions - never, if they are easy. Badly formatted - always. With bad English - mostly (poor people who hadn't the luck to be born in Eng-speaking land!) And the hard ones - if they are not about some exotic tech, but on the usual tech, but require depth or thinking or research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling `Bitmap.recycle` after you've finished with one Bitmap but before you load the next.

The problem is, that even than maybe won't help - Bitmaps can't resize themselves.

Maybe, better make array of bitmaps - one for ever path.

I am afraid, that java machine (or compiler) due to optimization doesn't destroy the previous bitmap, but tries to reuse it. Please, write here about results. It is interesting.

try to read the size of images not reading them:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

Bitmap btemp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath,options);
```

after this use below code to get height and width:

```
     options.outHeight     for height
      options.outWidth    for width
```

What do you see?

Try to change the order of the paths - again only the first will be OK? If not, the problem is in files. If yes, in connection/stream/factory.

Comment: I've tried this, but still nothing. I don't think that JVM can reuse previous value, because there is a BitmapFactory class, that always returns new instance

Comment: And loading bitmaps in different objects, too?

Comment: Try to change the order of the paths - again only the first will be OK? If not, the problem is in files. If yes, in connection/stream/factory.

Comment: Looks like that problem somewhere in stream. I've decided that using WebView instead will be more effective. However, thanks )

Comment: for nothing, pleasure is on my side. But it is a pity that I won't know about one more problem of stream/bitmap/connection.